# Traveling to mexico without visa. Do I need a return ticket?

Tags: visas, tourist-visas, mexico

I will be travelling to Mexico as a tourist (without visa), and I would like to know if I can just buy a one-way ticket for now and then get the return ticket later.

Thanks!

Comment: Where are you travelling from? And how long are you planning on staying in Mexico?

Comment: From Spain, and the plan is to find some job there to stay for a long period (couple of years probably)

Answer (score 2):

While Mexico offers visa-free entry to nationals of many country, border authorities can, and do, ask for itinerary information, including proof of onward travel (added emphasis mine):

> [Instituto Nacional de Migración](https://www.inm.gob.mx/gobmx/word/index.php/paises-no-requieren-visa-para-mexico/)
>
> **Countries and regions that do not require a visa to travel to Mexico**
>
> The nationals of the following countries or regions do not require a visa to travel to Mexico and apply for admission as a visitor without permission to perform remunerated activities.
>
> In the migratory review filter, they must present:
>
> 1. Passport or identity document and valid travel that is valid according to international law.
> 2. FMM duly completed.
> 3. The immigration authority may request the foreign person to verify the reason for their trip, by means of any of the following documents:
>
>    a) **Hotel reservation, return tickets (itinerary), tour tickets (itinerary)**.
>
>    b) A mandate letter in Spanish language of the parent company, subsidiary or foreign subsidiary that indicates that the foreign person is employed by it and that the payment of the services it will provide in the national territory will be paid by the same.
>
>    c) Copy of the technology transfer contract, patents and trademarks, purchase and sale of machinery and equipment, technical training of personnel, or any other related to the production process of a company established in Mexico or linking to the foreign party with the Mexican party, or proof of appointment by the shareholders' meeting of companies legally established in Mexico.
>
>    d) Letter from an organization or public or private institution inviting the foreign person to participate in any unpaid activity in the national territory, state the purpose of the visit and the estimated time of stay. In the event that the organization or institution pays the expenses of travel and permanence of the foreign person in the national territory, a responsive letter must be attached.
>
>    e) Letter of invitation or acceptance from an institution belonging to the National Educational System to carry out courses, studies or research or training projects for a maximum period of one hundred and eighty days.

Answer (score 1):

When traveling to Mexico as a tourist, there are two points where you might be asked to show a return or onward ticket: By the airline when checking in, and/or by the immigration officer upon arrival. Some airlines are more strict than others; I've never been asked by Interjet. In the worst case you might have to buy a return ticket on the spot to be allowed to board your plane. Google "proof of onward travel" for possible [ways](http://whereispepenow.com/proof-of-onward-travel-solutions/) to handle this.